# Show menu actions only in certain fragments - NavigationComponents

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a navigation host activity that inflates 2 fragments, one the main host fragment and the event fragments, I need to show in the event fragment a menu action , but this menu action is also shown in the main fragment which I dont want to show

How do I show this menu only in the event fragment ?

### MainActivity

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            setupActionBar(navController)
        }

        private fun setupActionBar(navController: NavController) {
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
        }

        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
                    || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        }

        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        }

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item!!, Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment))
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
```

### Menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/eventsFragment"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|always"
        android:title="¿ Where to buy ?" />

</menu>
```

I need to show this menu only in the eventsFragment

### EventFragment

```
class EventsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false)
    }
```

But instead of just showing it just in the EventFragment it also shows it in the first fragment that MainActivity as hosts inflates

How can I just have this menu in my EventsFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity menuItem setVisible(false):

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
  MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
  val menuItem : MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.eventsFragment);
   if (menuItem!= null)
       menuItem.setVisible(false);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
 }
```

In EventsFragment setvisibility of menuitem to true as shown below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.eventsFragment)
    if (menuItem != null)
        menuItem.isVisible = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try considering Inflating the menu from inside the fragment. ie. fragments `onCreate()` method and destroying it from `onDestroy()` function of the fragment